# Facebook is not seeing my opengraph meta tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

If you view source on http://seeitornot.co/prometheus/771228969, you'll see html in the  including the following:

```
<meta property='og:title' content='Prometheus' />
<meta property='og:image' content='http://content9.flixster.com/movie/11/16/28/11162851_det.jpg' />
```

But then if you use the OpenGraph debugger that facebook provides, http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fseeitornot.co%2Fprometheus%2F771228969, it says `The 'og:title' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.` along with similar messages for all tags.

Note: I have the following as my  tag, `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">`

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, it looks like you're delivering the mobile version of the site to Facebook, and your mobile version doesn't have the meta tags. Try adding the meta tags to the mobile layout too.

You can test what Facebook sees on http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fseeitornot.co%2Fprometheus%2F771228969